# How can I disconnect a Metamask wallet from Uniswap?

Tags: metamask, uniswap

As soon as I go in Uniswap, it already loads the Metamask wallet that was used previously... but I do not want to use that Metamask wallet, I want to use a different Metamask wallet. How my I do this, please?

Comment: This sounds like a bug somewhere. Please ask https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us and post the answer here :)

Comment: I think only reinstalling connected wallet would help because there is no option mentioned in uniswap now

Answer (score 1):

You can disconnect a Metamask account from a dapp by clicking on the three dots menu on the top right (next to Account NN).

Select "Connected site" it will show a dapps list that were authorized to use the current account. You can remove the dapp from the authorized list with the trash can icon.

To authorize an account to use a dapp you have to select an already authorized account, then switch to the unauthorized one, a popup should appear asking for confirmation.